# How to describe the power operation on Lie groups?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, or its compact form over $\mathbb{R}$. Recall that the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ is of the form $G^{\mathrm{adj}}\rtimes \operatorname{Out}(\mathfrak{g})$, where $G^{\mathrm{adj}}$ is the adjoint form of $G$ and $\operatorname{Out}(\mathfrak{g})$ is the group of Dynkin diagram automorphisms.

A theorem of Kac parameterizes the conjugacy classes of finite-order elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$. It is quoted for example in Theorem 8.3.3.1 of [these lecture notes](http://categorified.net/LieQuantumGroups.pdf).

Briefly, you write down the affine Dynkin diagram of $\mathfrak{g}$, with its numbering (meaning numbers $m_i$ attached to each root, so that the affine root is given the number $m_0 = 1$, and the vector $\vec m$ is in the kernel of the Cartan matrix); then a finite-order element is, up to conjugacy, a pair $\rho \in \operatorname{Out}(\mathfrak{g})$ of order $r$ and some nonnegative rational numbers $a_i$ assigned to the roots of the $\rho$-folded Dynkin diagram (the *twisted* affine Dynkin diagram of the $\rho$-folded diagram of $\mathfrak{g}$), so that $\sum a_i m_i = 1/r$. (The order is the common denominator of the $a_i$.) These data are considered up to Dynkin diagram automorphism.

It is pretty easy to see why these data parameterize elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$. Indeed, the idea is to describe the maximal torus therein as $(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z) \otimes (\text{weight lattice})$, and then to track any further Weyl group actions.

> Is there a similarly simple description of the power operations $x \mapsto x^n$ on this set, for $n \in \mathbb Z$?

The easiest case is when $\rho = \mathrm{id}$, in which case the power operation is "$a_i \mapsto na_i$," more or less. But that map quickly destroys any bounds on $\sum a_i m_i$, so you need to subtract off some integers and then act by the Weyl group.

Comment: Do you mean "some nonnegative rational numbers $a_i$" (rather than $n_i$)?

Comment: Do you mean "the power operations $x\mapsto x^n$ on this set, for $n\in\mathbb Z$" rather than "for $a\in \mathbb Z$"?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Oops, yes, I will correct it.

Comment: Your description of finite  order elements of ${\rm Aut}(\mathfrak g)$seems to be not quite correct.  First, I suspect that you should assume that $\mathfrak g$ is simple. Second, in the case $\rho\neq 1$ you should attach numbers $m_i$ to the vertices of the *$\rho$-twisted* affine Dynkin diagram of $\mathfrak g$ rather than to the vertices of the affine Dynkin diagram of $\mathfrak g$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi I think all I need is that $\mathfrak{g}$ be semisimple. If it is not simple, then the Dynkin diagram may be disconnected, and there may be outer automorphisms that permute the components of the diagram. I *think* that what I'm calling "the twisted affine Dynkin diagram of the $\rho$-folded diagram of $\mathfrak{g}$" is what you are calling the "$\rho$-twisted affine Dynkin diagram", but perhaps I am using the terminology wrong?

Comment: I think that there is no standard terminology, and I find your terminology to be better than mine. Anyway, to vertices of what do you attach the numbers $m_i$, and how do you define them?